# How to set a Http Session parameter in a JPA named query

Tags: session, jpa, ejb

I want to set a parameter in a named query (JPA 2.0), so my dataTable would render the respective dataSet. The parameter is obtained remotely and injected in a AbstractFacade class.

I've tried to achieve this through the code above, but it's not working.
Can someone help me?

AbstractFacade (main code):

```
private String prefDep;

public List<T> findByPrefDep() {
    prefDep=  FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getSessionMap().get("xPrefDep");
    javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = getEntityManager().getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
    cq.select(cq.from(entityClass));
    return getEntityManager().createQuery(cq).setParameter("prefDep", prefDep).getResultList();
}
```

The Entity class (main code):

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Capacitacao.findByPrefDep", query = "SELECT c FROM Capacitacao c WHERE c.prefDep = :prefDep"),
```

The AbstractController:

```
public Collection<T> getItems() {
    if (items == null) {
        items = this.ejbFacade.findByPrefDep();
    }
    return items;
}
```

There is no exception launched, but the dataSet rendered corresponds to a findAll named query.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code doesn't use your named query at all. A named query has a name, and your code doesn't use that name anywhere.

Use

```
getEntityManager().createNamedQuery("Capacitacao.findByPrefDep", Capacitacao.class)
                  .setParameter("prefDep", prefDep)
                  .getResultList();
```

You could have found that yourself by simply reading the [EntityManager javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/EntityManager.html).